# Reassign all ints with a specific value in 2d array Java

Tags: java, java-stream

Supppose I have a 2d array, grid defined like so:

```
    int[][] x = new int[][]{{0,0,1},{0,0,2},{0,0,3}};
```

Now suppose I want to reassign all positions in the grid with value 0 to Integer.MAX_VALUE

I can do this in Java 10:

```
        for(var row : grid) 
            for(int i=0; i<row.length; i++) 
                if(row[i] ==0) row[i]=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Is there a way I can make this shorter without creating a new array? I know I can use streams, but won't that create a new array, wasting memory?

Comment: If you override set your `x` reference to the new value of the stream result it won't waste memory assuming nothing else is referencing the old value of `x`. However yes it would require memory allocation. However, I took a look at the java 10 docs and found one possible function that could reduce a line without having to allocate new memory. `Arrays.setAll` might be useful for replacing the inner `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just took a look at the Java 10 docs [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class to see what it might have to offer.

```
for(var row : arrayOfArrays)
    Arrays.setAll(row, i -> row[i] == 0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : row[i]);
```

Would only be helpful for removing one line, and is only applicable to inner loop.

Note that `List<E>` has a `forEach(Consumer<E>)` method (implemented from `Iterable<E>`) so you would be able to use `forEach` for the outer loop. However I was incorrect when I said you could try `List<List<int>>` because you would not be able to set the variable using the consumer variable. You could still do `List<int[]>` and then try the following.

```
List<int[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<>();
//Fill in values
listOfArrays.forEach(inner -> Arrays.setAll(inner, i -> inner[i] == 0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : inner[i]));
```

Comment: The parameter `i` is the *index*, not the value. By the way, when you have a `int[][] x`, you can use `Arrays.asList(x).forEach(row -> …);` (and it’s strange to call the inner array `outer`).

Comment: It was like 1 am when I wrote this. I do agree with your points and will update it.

Comment: Took a look at the docs again I see what you mean. Will update this now.